# AS3 Error #1034: Type Coercion failed:

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, types, runtime-error

I have a problem with this class, it throws a 1034 error : Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Green$ to flash.display.DisplayObject.

I believe it is linked to the bg variable.
A little help would be greatly apreciated
thanks

```
    public var bg1:Green;
    public var bg2:Red;     
    public var bg3:Blue;        
    public var bg:MovieClip;
    public var bgElements_arr : Array;
    public var bg_arr : Array;

    public function Level1(target:Stage) 
    {

        bg1 = new Green;
        bg2 = new Red;
        bg3 = new Blue;
        bgElements_arr = new Array(Green, Red, Blue);
        bg_arr = new Array();

        for(var bg_i:int =0; bg_i <5; bg_i++)
        {   

            bg=bgElements_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgElements_arr.length)];

            bg_arr.push(bg);
            target.addChild(bg);

        }
```

Comment: What's the Green's type?

Comment: It should be a movie clip. as it is a linkage to movie clip in the library

Comment: So try    target.addChild(bg as DisplayObject)

Comment: I think I made a mistake in the bgElements_arr declaration, I declare types instaead of variables....I will dig this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to add on stage Class constructor , not instance . Add 'new' keyword and it will work :

```
for(var bg_i:int =0; bg_i <5; bg_i++)
        {   

            bg= new bgElements_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgElements_arr.length)];

            bg_arr.push(bg);
            target.addChild(bg);

        }
```

Comment: thank you. In the begining I replaced the array declaration with :"bgElements_arr = new Array(bg1, bg2, bg3);"  and it worked partially, some of the elemnts were randomaly not showing up. your solution fixed everything. I am curious what magic was at work there.....

Comment: There is difference between Class and Instance . You can create Instance using keyword 'new' that create another Class object. You were using Classes from library , not Instances.